# UseDapp - How to get return value from a solidity function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to interact from a react-frontend with a smart contract.
I want to set a string and get it with a solidity function.
I can set the string, but get it with the returns statement from Solidity is the problem.
How can I get the return value and print it?

Error Message (the yay is the string I set before):

```
Object { status: "Fail", transaction: "yay", receipt: undefined, errorMessage: "transaction.wait is not a function", chainId: 42 }
```

My hook:

```
import { useContractFunction } from '@usedapp/core'
import { Contract } from "@ethersproject/contracts"

export function GetValue(contract: Contract) {
    const { state, send } = useContractFunction(contract, "getValue", {transactionName: ""})   
    return {state,  send}
}

export function SetValue(contract: Contract) {
    const { state, send } = useContractFunction(contract, "setValue", {transactionName: ""})   
    return {state,  send}
}
```

My react component:

```
import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core"
import { GetValue, SetValue } from "./../hooks/index"
import lotteryAbi from "./../chain-info/abi.json"
import networkMapping from "./../chain-info/map.json"
import { constants, utils } from "ethers"
import { Contract } from "@ethersproject/contracts"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Value = () => {
    // Smart Contract
    const { chainId } = useEthers()
    const { abi } = lotteryAbi
    const valueAddress = chainId ? networkMapping["42"]["ChangeValue"][0] : constants.AddressZero
    const valueInterface = new utils.Interface(abi)
    const valueContract = new Contract(valueAddress, valueInterface)

    // get smart contract functions
    const {state: statusGet, send: callGet} = GetValue(valueContract)
    const {state: statusSet, send: callSet} = SetValue(valueContract)

    // call smart contract functions if button pressed
    function getValue() {
        console.log(callGet())
    } 

    function setValue() {
        callSet(text)
    }

    // detect status changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Get:")
        console.log(statusGet)
    },[statusGet])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Set:")
        console.log(statusSet)
    },[statusSet])

    const [text, setText] = useState<string>("")
    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newText = event.target.value === "" ? "" : String(event.target.value)
        setText(newText)
        console.log(newText)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={setValue}>Set</button>
            <button onClick={getValue}>Get</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ChangeValue {
    string public value;

    function setValue(string memory _value) public {
        value = _value;
    }

    function getValue() public view returns (string memory) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The answers of the similar question are not helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: First code line in my question is the error message

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your code, do you mind if I give you codes needed in pure JS and ethers.js library?!

Comment: Thanks but then I start there first on my own :)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was [clearing the localStorage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/) `transactions` key. As mentioned on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/TrueFiEng/useDApp/issues/459

But that wasn't enough at first, it would constantly repopulate the bugged transaction.

Also, for me, I exceeded my API request limits on the default `getDefaultProvider('rinkeby')` provider. After getting my own [Infura API key](https://infura.io/product/ethereum) the cleared storage would remain empty, since I believe useDapp was still retrying to send the transaction which is why it wouldn't go away when I originally just cleared localStorage.